# How to build an app with a CERTAIN version of webview?

Tags: javascript, cordova, flutter, webview

I need to create an app that will open my URL **in a certain** (not the latest) version of WebView and Chrome. **Certain version** is the most important part of my question.

Let's say Android Browser 4.0 (like Chrome 74.0.3729.186).
I also will need similar apps for testing other WebView versions. Not only for Android but for apple devices as well.

Is it possible? And if yes, what is the fastest way to create that testing app?

I googled some tutorials on how to basically integrate a WebView in a Native app, Flutter project or Cordova, but I can't find a way how to use an exact version of a WebView.

Comment: In Flutter, you can specify exact version of webview in the file pubspec.yaml. Won't it help ?

Comment: Yes, it would help. can you specify please how to do it? which flutter dependency do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, pubspec.yaml file contains dependencies E.g. WebView.

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^5.4.0    # any 5.4.x version where x >= 0 works.
  image_picker: '5.4.3'   # only version 5.4.3 works.
```

More details are at [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)

Comment: ok, so what dependency should I use in Flutter to open URL using "Android Browser 4.0 (like Chrome 74.0.3729.186)"?